# Get Row Position instead of Row Index from iterrows() in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I'm new to stackoverflow and I have research but have not find a satisfying answer.

I understand that I can get a row index by using df.iterrows() to iterate through a df. But what if I want to get a row position instead of row idx. What method can I use?

Example code that I'm working on is below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April'],
               'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
               'sale':[55, 40, 84, 31]})

df = df.set_index('month')

for idx, value in df.iterrows():
    print(idx)
```

How can I get an output of:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can get it by `df.index`

Comment: i think the question you should ask is "how do I answer my question without using `df.iterrows()`"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need row number instead of index, you should:

1. Use `enumerate` for a counter within a loop.
2. Don't extract the index, see options below.

**Option 1**

In most situations, for performance reasons you should try and use `df.itertuples` instead of `df.iterrows`. You can specify `index=False` so that the first element is not the index.

```
for idx, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(index=False)):
    # do something
```

[`df.itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples) returns a namedtuple for each row.

**Option 2**

Use [`df.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows). This is more cumbersome, as you need to separate out an unused variable. In addition, this is inefficient vs `itertuples`.

```
for idx, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, (_, value) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    print(idx)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get_loc` on df.index:

```
for idx, value in df.iterrows():
    print(idx, df.index.get_loc(idx))
```

Output:

```
Jan 0
Feb 1
March 2
April 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.index()` which returns a range of indexes numbers. The returned value is a `RangeIndex` object which is a `range` like iterable that supports iteration and many other functionalities that a Pandas series supports :

```
>>> df.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
>>> 
>>> list(df.index)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```